How to express fractional programming problem with DCP
Let $f(\theta) \triangleq \mathbf{a}^T(\theta) \mathbf{x} + b(\theta)$, where $\mathbf{a}(\theta) \in \mathbb{C}^N$, $\mathbf{x} \in [0,1]^N$, $b(\theta) \in \mathbb{C}$, with $\theta \in [-\pi,\pi[$.
I want to express the following unconstrained optimization problem using DCP rules.
\begin{equation}
\min_{\mathbf{x}} \left\{ \frac{\max_{\theta \in \Theta} |f(\theta)|}{|f(\theta_0)|} \right\}
\end{equation}
with $\Theta \subset [-\pi,\pi[$.
Let me show you my attempt.
First I take care of the numerator, so I introduce an auxiliar variable $\mu$ such that
\begin{equation}
|f(\theta)| \leq \mu, \, \forall \theta \in \Theta.
\end{equation}
Then I introduce a constraint in order to consider the denominator.
\begin{equation}
|f(\theta_0)| = \delta
\end{equation}
In order to remove the fractional form of the cost function I introduce a constraint on the minimum ratio.
\begin{equation}
\mu - R \, \delta \leq 0
\end{equation}
So the new problem can be formulated as below.
\begin{equation}
\min_{\mathbf{x}} \, \mu, \quad \text{u.c.} \quad
\begin{cases}
|f(\theta)| \leq \mu, \, \forall \theta \in \Theta \\
|f(\theta_0)| = \delta \\
\mu - R \, \delta \leq 0 \\
x_i \in [0,1], \, \forall i \in \{1,2,\ldots,N\}
\end{cases}.
\end{equation}
The last formulation is DCP unless the equality constraint $|f(\theta_0)| = \delta$.
How can I formulate the problem as DCP (possibly without the constraint on the minimum ratio)?

Is $\theta_0$ a given real constant?

Hello @RobPratt. Yes, it is.

Did you instead mean $\min_x R$?

Isn't $R$ supposed to represent the ratio to be minimized?  With your current formulation, $R$ plays no role and the constraint can be removed.

Yes, your are right! $R$ represents the ratio I liked to minimize in the original problem. Actually, the problem is that I want to jointly increase $\delta$ and reduce $\mu$. Which is the better way to relax the original problem in order to obtain a convex optimization problem?
